# relations of galois field to bitoperators in C

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields

Are bit operators in C corelated somehow to Galois field. Is there any literature (or beginner tutorials)  on it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. But bit operators or logic operators are functions from $\mathbb F_2\times \mathbb F_2$ to $\mathbb F_2$. What kind of correlation are you asking?

Comment: I needed any start point for how to interpret that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XORing (`a = b ^ c`) of $n$-bit values corresponds to addition of vectors in $\Bbb F_2^n$. Since $\Bbb F_{2^n}\cong \Bbb F_2^n$ as vector spaces over $\Bbb F_2$, this also emulates addition in $\Bbb F_{2^n}$. Multiplication in $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ is a whole different story, and other bit operations (`&`, `|`) do not have such a nice interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

As Hagen von Eitzen points out, the bitwise XOR operator `^` corresponds to addition in $\mathbb F_{2^n}$, while the other bitwise operators `&`
and `|` do not.

Two other bitwise operators (the shift operators `>>` and `<<`) also can be viewed
as providing some support for operations in $\mathbb F_{2^n}$. 
Think of  $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ as the set of binary polynomials of
degree less than $n$ with field addition and field multiplication
being polynomial addition and multiplication *modulo* an
irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$. Then, for example, 
if $1011$ corresponds
to the polynomial in $x^3+x+1$ in $\mathbb F_{2^4}$, the left
shift operator applied to $1011$ yields 
$10110 \leftrightarrow x^4+x^2+x$, that is, multiplication of
$x^3+x+1$ by $x$
while the right shift operator yields $101 \leftrightarrow  x^2+1$,
that is, the *quotient* when $x^3+x+1$ is *divided* by $x$.

Thus, the shift operators
operators can be used (in conjunction with `^`) to write
subroutines for multiplication and division in 
$\mathbb F_{2^n} = \mathbb F_2[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Comment: now I have better understanding of the field.